# A model category for descent?

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-categories, infinity-categories, descent, infinity-topos-theory

Recall that an $(\infty,1)$-category $C$ is said to have *descent* if for any small diagram $X:I\to M$ with (homotopy) colimit $\overline{X}$, the adjunction between $C/\overline{X}$ and "equifibered" $I$-diagrams over $X$ is an equivalence.  Here a natural transformation $Y\to X$ is called *equifibered* (or *cartesian*) if each naturality square is a (homotopy) pullback, the left adjoint $(C^I/X)_{\mathrm{equifibered}} \to C/\overline{X}$ takes (homotopy) colimits, and the right adjoint takes pullbacks.  This is described in a model-categorical context in Rezk's [Toposes and homotopy toposes](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~rezk/homotopy-topos-sketch.pdf) and using quasicategories in section 6.1.3 of Lurie's *Higher Topos Theory*.

My question is, can this equivalence be phrased as a Quillen equivalence of model categories?  In particular, given a sufficiently nice model category $M$ and a diagram $X:I\to M$ (perhaps simplicially enriched), is there a model category which presents the homotopy theory of equifibered diagrams over $X$, and for which the above homotopy-colimit adjunction is represented by a point-set-level Quillen adjunction (which would then be a Quillen equivalence when $M$ satisfies descent)?

I expect the answer is probably yes, and I can guess how to go about it, but I'm hoping someone else has worked out the details already.